# Passing different symbols as a parameter depending on the enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols, httparty

I started learning ruby today and I'm having a hard time understanding symbols and how to use them properly.

Right now I'm working on a simple server and website, and when I'm testing on the remote server I use the `:TLSv1` certificate, and on my local machine the `:SSLv23` certificate just because it works without having anything else.

So to not have to change the certificate when testing on those different environments -- because I can forget to change -- I tried to set up a flag for them like this:

```rb
if ENV['environment'] == 'development'
  ssl_method = ":SSLv23"
else
  ssl_method = ":TLSv1"
end

response = HTTParty.get('mywebsite.com/', :ssl_version => ssl_methos.to_sym)
```

It's not working. It returns this error when I'm trying to connect to localhost:

```sh
undefined local variable or method `ssl_method' for #<service> Did you mean? method
```

What alternative can I use?

**UPDATE**

Well, I dont know if there is a better alternative so I changed to this and worked.

```rb
if ENV['environment'] == 'development'
  $ssl_method = "SSLv23"
else
  $ssl_method = "TLSv1"
end

response = HTTParty.get('mywebsite.com/', :ssl_version => $ssl_method.to_sym)
```

I forgot to remove the `:` from the string and I had to use the `$` to define as a global variable. I am a python guy so I never thought that a global variable here would be different.

Comment: Please look for variable scopes in ruby and learn when to use what kind of scope. The $ variable works but is strongly discouraged, because global variables can be changed anywhere in ruby application. Try to initialize your local var before the if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ssl_method =
  if ENV['environment'] == 'development'
    :SSLv23
  else
    :TLSv1
  end

response = HTTParty.get('mywebsite.com/', :ssl_version => ssl_method)
```

The 2 ssl methods are just symbols in my example. In your `get` call you were just casting them back to symbols with `to_sym`, but you don't need to convert them if you initialize them as symbols.

Your code sample has a typo (`methos`), but I think I know the root cause of the error (or at least have a reasonable guess because I did the same thing when I was testing the behavior).

In your code snippet you used `ssl_method` (singular, for the 2 assignments), but in your `get` call you tried to call/look for the `ssl_methods` variable (plural, in the HTTParty call).

Since `ssl_methods` wasn't ever assigned as a variable or defined as a method Ruby thought you might have meant to call the `method` method (which is actually a method in ruby)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to define a global variable and there is no issue with using symbols here, I noticed a typo here

`HTTParty.get('mywebsite.com/', :ssl_version => ssl_methos.to_sym)`

`ssl_methos` you need to change to `ssl_method` as you did with global var.